# Unity3d FullInspector and Json.net not serializing data

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, json.net, inspector

**Problem:** I'm having a hard time serializing data with full inspector and json.net.

Here is a example of a simple test I just ran. I have both json.net and full inspector in the project. When I place the test script on an object in the scene I can see the exposed model object and edit its properties. However when I run the application none of the data persists. Am I missing something?

I see there is a ref wrapper [in the documentation](http://jacobdufault.github.io/fullinspector/guide-1.2.html#usage), but that seems to be for serializing behavior references, not standard objects. (maybe I am wrong)

```
using FullInspector;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class test : BaseBehavior
{
    public JsonModel model;

}

public class JsonModel : BaseObject
{
    [JsonProperty(propertyName: "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

You can see once I run the project in the unity editor, the data disappears. (running is indicated by the tint in color)

[image]

The reason the above code has an attribute is because that is intended to be a json.net object so I can deserialize responses from my cms and bind the data to this object. That is not the only use for this model object though, I want to be able to expose it in the editor and manually plug data and save the data ( because some content will be housed locally and has the same structure ) .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JsonModel` is serialized by Unity - it needs a `[Serializable]` annotation.

Please note that `BaseObject` only supports Full Serializer; this will work as is however because FS will serialize auto-properties by default.